# Split from list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my list I have few items, i.e.,

```
List=['a/c/d/eww/d/df/rr/e.jpg', 'ss/dds/ert/eww/ees/err/err.jpg','fds/aaa/eww/err/dd.jpg']
```

I want to keep only from 'eww' till last '/'

```
Modified_list=['eww/d/df/rr/', 'eww/ees/err/err.jpg','eww/err/']
```

Comment: what is the rule to either keep the left part or the right part of the string?

Answer (score 1):

Use `find(sub_str)` function.

```
new_list = [item[item.find("eww"):] for item in List]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['eww/d/df/rr/e.jpg', 'eww/ees/err/err.jpg', 'eww/err/dd.jpg']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list2=[item[item.find('eww'):item.rfind('/')+1] for item in List]
print(new_list2)
```

output=   ['eww/d/df/rr/', 'eww/ees/err/', 'eww/err/']

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I would do:

1. split the string after `eww`
   assuming that each string contains 'eww' you can split the string like this: `split = 'eww'+string.split('eww')[1]`
2. Now, you have to loop over each character in the remaining string and save the index of the last `/`
3. Remove everything after the last `/` with the index from step 3: `split = split[:splitIndex]`
4. Now, you just have to put everything in a loop that iterates over the list and execute each of the steps above on each element of the list and save the modified string to the ModiefiedList list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex in a list comprehension.

A perfect use case for the new [walrus operator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) (python ≥3.8):

```
List=['a/c/d/eww/d/df/rr/e.jpg',
      'ss/dds/ert/eww/ees/err/err.jpg',
      'fds/aaa/eww/err/dd.jpg']

import re
out = [m.group() if (m:=re.search('eww/(.*)/', s)) else s
       for s in List]
```

output:

```
['eww/d/df/rr/', 'eww/ees/err/', 'eww/err/']
```

*NB. this keeps the original string in case of no match, if you rather want to drop it*:

```
out = [m.group() for s in List if (m:=re.search('eww/(.*)/', s))]
```